# Grouping columns with aliases

Tags: sql, oracle

alright, I've got a pretty simple query - three columns, the first I want to group by the second and the third is simply a count. The first column, ID, has a dozen values. The second, CODE has six. If I do a simple select

`SELECT ID,CODE,THINGIMCOUNTING FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID`

What I'd like is for the columns to be aliases of the ID column so that the CODE columns don't repeat, since multiple IDs can reference the same CODE, I can't do a single group by without duplication - just want to clean it up a bit.

my first thought was aliasing, but that doesn't seem to be an option in Oracle SQL - for instance

`SELECT ID as FIRST_ID, ID  as SECOND_ID, ID as THIRD_ID, CODE, THINGIMCOUNTING<BR>
WHERE FIRST_ID = "1" AND SECOND_ID="2" AND THIRD_ID="3" GROUP BY CODE`

or something to that effect. Then I read about the `INTERSECT` keyword, but when I use it I get no results - just the columns. something like

`SELECT IDELECT ID,CODE,THINGIMCOUNTING FROM TABLE<BR>WHERE ID = "1" GROUP BY CODE`
`INTERSECT`
`SELECT IDELECT ID,CODE,THINGIMCOUNTING FROM TABLE<BR>WHERE ID = "2" GROUP BY CODE`

I'm trying to get a matrix like display out of the query alone - am I over complicating this? is there a simple, elegant solution I'm not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: Please show sample data for the tables, and expected output.

Comment: This `SELECT ID,CODE,THINGIMCOUNTING FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID` is valid only in mysql. Every column in the select needs to be either grouped by or part of an aggregate.

Comment: use union instead of intersect and don't select the id

Comment: I'll try using union tomorrow, thanks

Comment: @ConradFrix this is just a sample, I'm grouping on everything that isn't aggregated (the count) - I'm more curious about the layout I was describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy just use the Pivot clause

```
Select * 
from
(   Select  id, 
            code, 
            THINGIMCOUNTING
     from table1)
Pivot 
  ( count(THINGIMCOUNTING) for id in (1 as id1 ,
                                      2 as id2 ,
                                      3 as id3))
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/053c4/6)

An alternative is to use SUM/ CASE

```
Select 
    code,
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 1 then 1 ELSE 0 END) id1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) id2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN id = 3 then 1 ELSE 0 END) id3
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
  Code
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/053c4/9)

Comment: this is a great small scale solution! however, and I should have mentioned this, my table has millions and millions of rows, so, the query has been running for 10 minutes and still going

Comment: the pivot option is significantly faster - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

This query really belongs at the bottom of the answer, because I didn't come up with it at first. But to cut to the chase... something like this may return the resultset you specified.

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 1 THEN i.id END) AS id1
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 2 THEN i.id END) AS id2
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 3 THEN i.id END) AS id3
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 4 THEN i.id END) AS id4
     , s.CODE
     , s.cnt_
  FROM ( SELECT t.CODE
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt_
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP BY t.CODE
       ) s
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.CODE ORDER BY j.ID ASC) rn
              , j.CODE
              , j.ID
           FROM mytable j
       ) i
    ON i.CODE = s.CODE
 GROUP BY s.CODE, s.cnt_
```

(I had to dig into the Oracle documentation to find the syntax for the analytic function that can assign row numbers by a group).

---

**ORIGINAL**

I'm not sure what resultset you are looking for. It sounds like you want DISTINCT values of CODE, and you want to get `counts` by distinct code values.

That part is easy, right:

```
 SELECT t.CODE
      , COUNT(1)
   FROM mytable t
  GROUP BY t.CODE
```

returns

```
code count
---- -----
fee      4
fi       2
fo       3
```

If that's the number of rows you are looking for, and the value of count you want returned, it's a bit of a problem to get the ID values corresponding to that code on the same line.

Assuming,

```
SELECT t.CODE
     , t.ID
  FROM mytable t
 ORDER BY t.CODE, t.ID
```

returns:

```
code id
---- --
fee   2
fee   3
fee   5
fee   7
fi   11
fi   13
fo    4
fo    6
fo    8
```

such that this query gets you the "list" of ID values you want returned for each code, but these are on separate rows, you want to represent this in a resultset that looks something like this:

```
id1 id2 id3 id4 code count
--- --- --- --- ---- -----
  2   3   5   7  fee     4
 11  13          fi      2
  4   6   8      fo      3
```

That's a bit of a problem. For one thing, the number of columns has to be specified in the statement, it can't be changed dynamically when the statement runs. So, there would need to be an upper bound on the number of id values that could be returned.

But, it's not at all clear that's the resultset you are really looking for.  An example would go a long ways towards explaining the result you are trying to achieve.

There may be an analytic function that can do this type of pivot easily, but getting this result using plain old ANSI SQL is likely going to be some horrendous SQL text.

I'd recommend looking into the analytic functions.

The "trick", as I see it, is going to be getting the id values assigned "row numbers" within each code.

If you can get a resultset that looks like this, with an ascending row number within each code value:

```
code rn id
---- -- --
fee   1  2
fee   2  3
fee   3  5
fee   4  7
fi    1 11
fi    2 13
fo    1  4
fo    2  6 
fo    3  8
```

Then you could something like this. The query (whatever that is) that can produce the resultset with the rn rownumber would be inserted into this query as an inline view, shown aliased as `i` in here:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 1 THEN i.id END) AS id1
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 2 THEN i.id END) AS id2
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 3 THEN i.id END) AS id3
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 4 THEN i.id END) AS id4
     , s.CODE
     , s.cnt_
  FROM ( SELECT t.CODE
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt_
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP BY t.CODE
       ) s
  LEFT
  JOIN ( 
         -- SELECT code, rn, id --
       ) i
    ON i.CODE = s.CODE
 GROUP BY s.CODE, s.cnt_
```

That's using a conditional expression in the SELECT list to return the id value, depending on the value of `rn`.  rn=1 is returned into the first column (on the row with the matching CODE), rn=2 is returned into the second column. The "trick" really is in NOT returning the id value when its not the 'right' row number. We have to wrap those in some sort of aggregate function, in order to get a GROUP BY on the outer query to work.

You can probably make use of an analytic/windowing type function to assign the "row number" to each id for each code.  Seems like I've seem some syntax something like (and I know this isn't right, I'm just taking a stab at it...)

I'm not sure if that can be used in an inline view (I think it can in Oracle), but I think there's differences between the syntax in Oracle and SQL Server, (and differences in the actual functions that are supported). This type of analytic function is totally absent from MySQL.

---

**UPDATE**

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100

Looks like the syntax to get the row number column would actually be:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.CODE ORDER BY j.ID ASC) rn
     , j.CODE
     , j.ID
  FROM mytable j
```

So, something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 1 THEN i.id END) AS id1
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 2 THEN i.id END) AS id2
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 3 THEN i.id END) AS id3
     , MIN(CASE WHEN i.rn = 4 THEN i.id END) AS id4
     , s.CODE
     , s.cnt_
  FROM ( SELECT t.CODE
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt_
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP BY t.CODE
       ) s
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.CODE ORDER BY j.ID ASC) rn
              , j.CODE
              , j.ID
           FROM mytable j
       ) i
    ON i.CODE = s.CODE
 GROUP BY s.CODE, s.cnt_
```

---

Comment: That's a lot to take in! I'll see what I can put together  - thank you for the insight

Comment: @nbpeth: I'm not sure I "got" the resultset you were looking for. If you go this route, try running just the queries inside the inline views (aliased as `s` and `i` in my query), and get those working first. Once you have those working, you can think of them as being tables with really long names... my editor lets me collapse the inline views, `+   FROM (SELECT t.CODE` and the next line is `  ) s`... helps to see the structure of the outer query when those inline views get big and hairy. Divide and conquer.

Comment: @nbpeth: if you are looking for a different resultset, you can give an example in your question. For example, if you are looking for a "crosstab" type report, with a count by "code" on one axis, and a count by "id" on another, we'd do that quite a bit differently.